# Detect if the file uploaded is password protected on the browser - Javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload

Looking to see if it is possible to detect if an uploaded file is password protected or not. Eg. .PST (Clientside)

Mainly focussing on .PST files

Comment: I don't think so. The browser doesn't know anything about application file formats.

Comment: Password protection systems built into file formats are file format specific. Determining if a file of type "zip, pdf, etc" is password protected is too broad a question for SO. You should focus on one type.

Comment: @Barmar — But it can read files, so it is possible to write JavaScript which knows about application file formats.

Comment: Yeah, but you would then need to know about all possible file format.

Comment: Lets scope the question to deal with password protected .PST

Comment: I'd look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/pst-extractor then. I don't have any PST files to run a test with, but it looks like it will [throw an error if the file is encrypted](https://github.com/epfromer/pst-extractor/blob/master/src/PSTFile.class.ts#L144) which I suspect aligns with password protection in the format.